# Using dplyr filter with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data set.

There are three columns: Pentad, A, and B.

```
library(zoo)
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse) 

dat<-structure(list(Pentad = 50:73, A = c(152.796, 
109.678, 91.5594,115.155, 135.9, 202.441, 71.6951, 
88.3894, 261.962,135.853, 89.3425, 110.674, 100.558, 
173.507, 87.2157, 86.6425, 75.1852, 57.403, 62.5705, 
49.6846, 52.0257, 92.819, 105.419, 97.7598), 
B = c(145.402, 110.109, 83.1076, 95.3952, 148.571, 
119.178, 56.5031, 76.2635, 260.443, 109.705, 62.3749, 
100.322, 88.4134, 135.721, 63.1486, 69.7161, 62.3886, 
46.4513, 52.4546, 42.7725, 45.7643, 79.5419, 79.9434, 
87.6405)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I would like to implement the following condition in R.

```
[1] V1 should be between 0 and 90 at the time step (excluding 0 and 90)

[2] In the succeeding FOUR time steps (including the 
timestep in [1]), V1 between 0 and 90 in AT LEAST THREE timesteps
```

What I have so far:

```
 test2 <- function(dat, column_name){ 
   dat %>%
   rownames_to_column() %>%
   filter((.data[[column_name]] > 0 & .data[[column_name]] < 90) & 
         rollsum(.data[[column_name]] > 0 & .data[[column_name]] < 90, 4, fill = NA, align = 
                   "left") >= 3) %>%
   slice(1) -> result
  return(result)
}

out <- colnames(dat2) %>% 
  set_names %>% 
  map_dfr(~ test2(dat2, .x), .id = 'Col_ID')
```

PROBLEM:

I want to get the timestep/pentad value where the above three conditions are true for both the 2nd (column A) and 3rd columns (column B).

That is, the timestep when both columns satisfy the conditions at the same time.

The expected output is Pentad 64.

Any idea how can I implement this in R?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you include your expected output for the example shared?

Comment: @RonakShahI added the expected output. It should be pentad 64 on the first column.

Comment: How does it satisfy `Accumulated value of the next FOUR timesteps 
(including the timestep in [1]) should be less than -1.` ? the sum of next 4 values is definitely more than -1.

Comment: OMG..haha...thank you for pointing this out. It is not included in the criteria!

Comment: pentad 65, 66 satisfy that condition as well, right?

Comment: yes @RonakShah..but I am looking for the first pentad occurrence satisfying all the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt very close to OP's attempt.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

test2 <- function(dat) {
   dat %>%
      filter_at(vars(A:B), all_vars(. > 0 & . < 90 & 
                     rollsum(. > 0 & . < 90, 4, fill = NA) >= 3)) %>%
       slice(1L)
}

test2(dat)

#  Pentad       A       B
#1     64 87.2157 63.1486
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak..If I understand this correctly, the function was just applied to column A. It is just a coincidence that column B satisfies the criteria at the same pentad. What if column B satisfies the criteria at pentad 65? Then the common between columns A and B is pentad 65 now.

Comment: In that case no need to pass any column name since you want to check for both the columns. See updated answer.